# Running Maintenance Plan Wizard

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I've upgraded a server from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 but the database runs slower when running certain stored procedures especially against records which contain more data than others.

It's been suggested that I run a basic reindex to see if this resolves.

Can someone take a look at the screenshot and advise if this will remove any data from my database - if so then this isn't the right thing to do.

Thanks James

p.s I will now attach a screen-shot if I can as not done that before using this Forum

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those actions won't remove any data from the database, but generally I wouldn't advise trying to shrink the database unless you really need the space as this can cause more fragmentation of indexes.  The only options that you have ticked there that have the ability to improve performance are the rebuild/reorganise indexes and the update statistics options.

Rather than maintenance plans though I would generally recommend using Ola Hallengren's DB maintenance scripts though as they offer more flexibility and are generally a lot better than these plans:

[Ola Hallengren - SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

Comment: Thanks Steoleary. I'm using the inbuilt Wizards at the moment as this is where I am in my DBA journey so far. As long as the server performance either stays the same or improve then I'll be happy with this for now